# Powershell move files and folders based on older than x days

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item, file-move

I am new to powershell and trying to learn a basic file move from one directory to another. My goal is to move files and folders that are over 18months old to cold storage folder run as a scheduled Task. I need to be able to easily modify it's directories to fit our needs. It needs to preserve the folder structure and only move files that fit the above parameters. I also need it to log everything it did so if something is off i know where.
If I run this it just copies everything. If I comment out the %{Copy-Item... then it runs and lists only based on my parameters and logs it. Where am I going wrong or am I way off base?

Yes it would be easy to use robocopy to do this but I want to use powershell and learn from it.

```
#Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; Remove-Module *; $error.Clear();
#Clear-Host
#Days older than
$Days = "-485"
#Path Variables
$Sourcepath = "C:\Temp1"
$DestinationPath = "C:\Temp2"
#Logging
$Logfile = "c:\temp3\file_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).log"

#transcript logs all outputs to txt file 
Start-Transcript -Path $Logfile -Append
Get-ChildItem $Sourcepath -Force -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastwriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($Days)} | 
    % {Copy-Item -Path $Sourcepath -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -Force}
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: `$Days = "-485"` -- you are creating a string, not a number. It should be `$Days = -485`.

Comment: Made that change but still same thing happens. All files move and it never really "stops" running. If I comment out the copy-item it lists the correct data
Directory: C:\Temp1\jjahnke\01262017\Vineze\Zebra\Pics


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         9/17/2008   2:59 PM         391858 LabelPath.jpg
-a----         4/11/2012  11:33 AM         148448 RedBeam.jpg
-a----         9/17/2008   2:58 PM         374728 RedSensorLever.jpg
-a----         9/17/2008   2:57 PM         376095 Sensors.jpg

Comment: @StormySkies - PLEASE, don't post more than a very few words of code/errors/data in the comments ... put it all in the Question so that it can be read easily.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

> ```
> Copy-Item -Path $Sourcepath -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -Force
> ```

You always specify the same path for source and destination. With parameter `-recurse` you will copy the whole directory `$SourcePath` for each matching file.

### Solution

You need to feed the output of the previous pipeline steps to `Copy-Item` by using the `$_` (aka `$PSItem`) variable, basically using `Copy-Item` in single-item mode.

Try this (requires .NET >= 5.0 for `GetRelativePath` method):

```
Get-ChildItem $Sourcepath -File -Force -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastwriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($Days)} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $relativeSourceFilePath = [IO.Path]::GetRelativePath( $sourcePath, $_.Fullname )
        $destinationFilePath    = Join-Path $destinationPath $relativeSourceFilePath
        $destinationSubDirPath  = Split-Path $destinationFilePath -Parent 

        # Need to create sub directory when using Copy-Item in single-item mode
        $null = New-Item $destinationSubDirPath -ItemType Directory -Force

        # Copy one file
        Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $destinationFilePath -Force 
    }
```

Alternative implementation without `GetRelativePath` (for .NET < 5.0):

```
Push-Location $Sourcepath   # Base path to use for Get-ChildItem and Resolve-Path

try {
    Get-ChildItem . -File -Force -Recurse | 
        Where-Object {$_.LastwriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($Days)} | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $relativeSourceFilePath = Resolve-Path $_.Fullname -Relative
            $destinationFilePath    = Join-Path $destinationPath $relativeSourceFilePath
            $destinationSubDirPath  = Split-Path $destinationFilePath -Parent 

            # Need to create sub directory when using Copy-Item in single-item mode
            $null = New-Item $destinationSubDirPath -ItemType Directory -Force

            # Copy one file
            Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $destinationFilePath -Force 
        }
}
finally {
    Pop-Location   # restore previous location
}
```

On a side note, `$Days = "-485"` should be replaced by `$Days = -485`.
You currently create a string instead of a number and rely on Powershell's ability to automagically convert string to number when "necessary". This doesn't always work though, so better create a variable with the appropriate datatype in the first place.

Comment: This makes sense on why  you chose to go this route. But when I run it I am getting errors. It may be because of how I am using this file. I currently had it set to look at local c drive but it's intention is to work on remote work. i would run it from task server to move files between 2 servers. 

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.Path] does not contain a method named 'GetRelativePath'.
PS>TerminatingError(New-Item): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string."
New-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
Ideas?

Comment: @StormySkies This failed because `GetRelativePath` requires .NET 5.0 or newer. I have added an alternative implementation using `Resolve-Path`. Also I have added `-File` argument for `Get-ChildItem` because we only want to get file paths. Destination directories will be created as needed.