# How do you do a selective copy from a directory tree using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell but have experience with Bash scripting and Python, but need to use PowerShell for a specific project. I thought my use-case was pretty easy, but am really having a hard time getting it to work.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
-- Data
   -- ProjectA
      -- Exception
         - exception1.txt
      -- Custom
         - file1.txt
         - file2.txt
   -- ProjectB
      -- Exception
         - exception2.txt
      -- Custom
         - file3.txt
         - file4.txt
```

What I am trying to do is copy this structure, but copy the 'Exception' directories and their contents to a different path to the rest of the files. So I want to end up with something like this:

```
-- NewFolder
   -- ProjectA
      -- Custom
         - file1.txt
         - file2.txt
   -- ProjectB
      -- Custom
         - file3.txt
         - file4.txt
-- ExceptionFolder
   -- Exception
      - exception1.txt
      - exception2.txt
```

Notice that the contents of the exception folders are all merged into a single folder.

I have tried with doing a Copy-Item and then `--exclude '*Exception*'` but that only seems to work if the 'Exception' folder is at the top level. So I then tried with Get-ChildItem and pipe that into a `where ($_fullname -notin '*Exception*')` and pipe that into further steps to copy at each level, but that doesn't seem to work either.  I've tried a few other things as well but none give me the results I'm looking for.

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using PowerShell 7.1.1 on a Mac.

Any guidance on this one would be much appreciated!

Comment: im so confused in regards to what youre asking for. So, you want to copy the contents of that folder to a different folder, but not copy the exception sub folder?

Comment: Yes.  Copy the contents of `Data` to a different path (`NewFolder`), but exclude any folder called `Exception`. Then, copy any folders called `Exception` to a different path (`NewFolder/Exception`).  

Effectively as part of my copy I'm wanting to move all the Exception folders out of the Project folders (ProjectA, ProjectB) and place them in a new location at a higher level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convoluted, yes, works? yes.

```
$source          = '.\Data'
$destination     = '.\New Folder'
$exceptionFolder = '.\ExceptionFolder'
$exceptionRegex  = 'Exception|foobar'

$directories = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Directory
$redirect = $directories | ? {$_.Name -match $exceptionRegex}


switch -Regex ($directories){
    {$_.Name -match $exceptionRegex} {
        
        # Create directory based on the regex match.
        $ExceptionDestination = [io.directoryinfo]("{0}\{1}" -f $ExceptionFolder, $_.Name)
        
        if (-not(Test-Path -Path $ExceptionDestination)){
            $null = md $ExceptionDestination
        }

        # Copy top level files from the matched directory name into the $ExceptionDestination directory.
        Copy-Item -Path ("{0}\*.*" -f $_.FullName) -Destination $ExceptionDestination -Verbose
    }
}

# Skips copying of the contents of directories matching $exceptionRegex.
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Exclude ("*{0}*" -f $redirect).Name -Recurse -Verbose

# Actually remove directories.
Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse -Directory | ? {$_.Name -match $exceptionRegex} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. There were some things that didn't work out exactly the same on Mac for some reason, but this was really helpful in enabling me to put together a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could try Robocopy ! You have an exclude parameter.

https://pureinfotech.com/exclude-files-folders-robocopy-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's part of a CI/CD build process and the build agents don't have Robocopy installed and I cannot mandate that it be installed. So I have to use PowerShell for this.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but, this might be what youre asking for?

```
#add -Recurse to copy subfolders
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Path1 -Exclude "Exception" | Copy-Item -Destination C:\Path2
```

Or,

```
#add -Recurse to copy subfolders
Copy-Item -Path C:\path1\* -Exclude 'Exception' -Destination C:\path2
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy all items, excluding files named like "Exception*" (there seems to be no way to exclude based on directory name, apart from a `Get-ChildItem` pipeline):

```
Copy-Item 'Data\*' -Destination 'NewFolder' -Exclude 'Exception*' -Recurse
```

Unfortunately this creates empty "Exception" folders in the destination, so we have to delete them:

```
Remove-Item 'NewFolder\*' -Include 'Exception' -Recurse
```

Here is an [example for a `Get-ChildItem` pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428281/7571258) in case you need a more general solution. You could change the `Where-Object` condition to filter on full path, e. g. `$_.Fullname -notlike '*\Exception\*'`.